# Skype like application on Microsoft Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, webrtc, http-live-streaming, videochat, azure-media-services

Currently I am working on an idea for a "Skype" like application. E.g people video call other people. Now I thought of running this on [Microsoft Azure Media Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/). However I'm not quite sure if this is possible.

I found this [video](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/getting-started-with-azure-media-services/) explaining how to make a simple stream from your computers webcam. What they do there is create a `Channel` (manually in the Azure environment) and stream to the `ingest url`. And the result can be seen in the `publish url`.

So far so good. I understand this. But this approach would not work for having people video chat with other people. (Every "videochat" would require its own `Channel` I suppose) and creating those manually would not work.

So I found that there is a REST API. To [create channels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783458.aspx#create_channels) via REST. Which would be a possibility. But creating a single `Channel` takes up to like 30 seconds. So this would not be the way to go I suppose either.

I think my question boils down to this. Is it possible to run a Skype like application on Windows Azure (Media Services) and if so. How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now live streaming in Azure Media services  will have 30-40 seconds delays between video captured and moment it streamed through published channel.

Architecture and goals are different. Azure Media services tailored to provide scalable live streaming solution which can have from 0 to several millions concurrent users watching your channel (2015 Super Bowl for example). Also it has capabilities to execute various media related workflows.
[Skype has a P2P architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol) to archive minimum delays for a given connection quality.

If mentioned above delay is not critical for your than you can utilize Azure Media services streaming, otherwise you need to use some solution based on p2p architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Azure does not support conferencing video streaming as a service.

But you can install any open source SFU/MCU appliance on Azure VMs.

Take a look to Kurento, Jitsi, Janus and others.

I do not think that p2p is the only option, as Skype and Google's WebRTC stack use media relays in case when peer to peer connection can't be established and delays are still within acceptable limits. There are much more than that in this subject.