# Can I use Azure Media Services as an 1-1 video chat?

Tags: azure-media-services

Can I use Azure Media Services as an 1-1 video chat?This would be something like skype/Discord or Teams

Comment: Short answer: no, not at this time. Checking for options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea will not work.

The purpose of Azure Media Services is to securely deliver on-demand and live video or audio streams that scale to millions of users.

In addition, Azure Media services will have 30-40 seconds delays between video captured and moment it streamed through published channel. Unable to meet your requirements, you can view Skype related technical information.

For more details, you can see the post. [Skype like application on Microsoft Azure Media Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334119/skype-like-application-on-microsoft-azure-media-services)